# Mono / ASP / lighttpd/ Linux: relative path not working

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, mono, lighttpd

Could not find file "~/pages/footer.htm". is the error im getting

the actual code segment is...

```
Response.WriteFile("~/pages/footer.htm");
```

I just installed lighttpd and set it up to run our asp app through mono about an hour ago on my ubuntu vm

and yes the footer.htm file exists in the location /pages/footer.htm  (where / is the root dir /var/www)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ~ in a path string because shell expansion rules don't get applied (same with c/c++).

Comment: Is this just a configuration issue? The pages I'm working on are directly taken from a working production server and I'm just setting them up on my local development machine. The tildes in the paths work fine in the production environment

Comment: also, the production server is a windows machine and the ~ works fine on it